# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'long'

Tags: c#, double, long-integer

In this code i got the above error in lines i commented.

```
public double bigzarb(long u, long v)
{
    double n;
    long x;
    long y;
    long w;
    long z;
    string[] i = textBox7.Text.Split(',');
    long[] nums = new long[i.Length];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < i.Length; counter++)
    {
        nums[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(i[counter]);
    }

    u = nums[0];
    int firstdigits = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(u) + 1));
    v = nums[1];
    int seconddigits = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(v) + 1));
    if (firstdigits >= seconddigits)
    {
        n = firstdigits;

    }
    else
    {
        n = seconddigits;        
    }
    if (u == 0 || v == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("the Multiply is 0");
    }

    int intn = Convert.ToInt32(n);
    if (intn <= 3)
    {
        long uv = u * v;
        string struv = uv.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(struv);
        return uv;
    }
    else
    {
        int m =Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(n / 2));

        x = u % Math.Pow(10, m); // here
        y = u / Math.Pow(10, m); // here
        w = v % Math.Pow(10, m); // here
        z = v / Math.Pow(10, m); // here

        long result = bigzarb(x, w) * Math.Pow(10, m) + (bigzarb(x, w) + bigzarb(w, y)) * Math.Pow(10, m) + bigzarb(y, z);///here
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Whats is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Math.Pow` method returns a `double`, not a `long` so you will need to change your code to account for this:

```
x = (long)(u % Math.Pow(10, m));
```

This code will cast the `double` result from `Math.Pow` and assign that value to `x`.  Keep in mind that you will lose all the precision providided by `decimal` (which is a floating-point type and can represent decimal values).  Casting to `long` will truncate everything after the decimal point.

Comment: Not to forget overflow when casting, which will totally mess things up. Example: `(long) double.MaxValue == -9223372036854775808`

Answer (score 5):

Change types

```
long x;
long y;
long w;
long z;
```

to

```
double x;
double y;
double w;
double z;
```

Or make use of

```
Convert.ToInt64
```

Comment: This will fix it, but this is a poor solution since he chose long for a reason and double types are the slowest type not counting Strings as a type.

Answer (score 5):

Math.Pow returns a double.

the Right Hand Side (RHS) of % can only be an integer type.

you need

```
x = u % (long)Math.Pow(10, m);///<----here
y = u / (long)Math.Pow(10, m);///here
w = v % (long)Math.Pow(10, m);///here
z = v / (long)Math.Pow(10, m);///here
```

Additionally, You have the possibility of dividing by zero and destroying the universe.

Comment: From your answer *the Right Hand Side (RHS) of % can only be an integer type*, but looking at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx I dont aggree...

Comment: Read this sentence that the website you site says. Note the error for the types float and double.

Comment: It is referring to rounding *errors*, not compile/runtime errors.

Comment: It would be better to cast the result of the modulus operation to `long` rather than just the result of `Math.Pow`.  Also keep in mind that if the compiler is able to work out that either `u` or `v` is a floating point type then your code still will not compile since the result of the expression will still not be implicitly convertible to `long`.  It's better to convert the result of the entire expression (as I have shown in my answer) to avoid all of these problems.

Answer (score 3):

Math.Pow returns a double. You could explicitly cast to long, for example

```
x = u % (long)Math.Pow(10, m);
```

although that is likely not the correct solution. Are you certain that the results that you are after can be properly expressed as a double? If not then change the variables to be declared as doubles rather than longs.

Comment: Though this is general something one should consider whenever using a cast from `double` to `long`, I suspect in this special case `m` will always be small enough.

Answer (score 2):

You cant' cast implicitly double to long, use (long) cast or change type of variable declaration to double.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this:

```
Convert.ToInt64( u % Math.Pow(10, m) )
```

Source [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwcsf0k4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The advantage of using [`Convert.ToInt64(double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64?view=netframework-3.5#system-convert-toint64(system-double)) being that it is documented to return the value ***rounded** to the nearest 64-bit signed integer* rather than truncated as is done by the `(long)` cast.